# Cygwin's rm async?

Tags: cygwin

I created a shell script running under Cygwin who copies around 1000 files to a directory, then processes them and delete all the files, to start the cycle again.

I noted the files are not deleted after "rm directory/*", but if I execute the same command from command line (outside my script) it does work as expected.

Can the problem be that rm is returning control to the script before it ends its execution?. How can I be sure all the files are removed before starting the process again?.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about this. The problem was rm can't handle a large list of files, the solution was using a for loop:

```
for f in *.c; do rm $f; done
```